# How to handle renewal of the auto-renewable subscriptions locally?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription, auto-renewable

I try to add auto-renewable subscriptions in my app, but not sure about the proper way to handle this.

What I'm having right now is

1. Add `SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)` in app delegate.
2. Once user purchase I save expiration date and set timer to fire on that date.
3. If I get renew transaction, update expiration date and extended timer.
4. If user not renew timer will fired and update ui to reflect that change.

My question is if this a right approach? This approach seem to have a gap where a brief moment (when date expired and renew transaction not yet arrived), users are treat as free tier.

What is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The app receipt contains a record of the user’s purchases, cryptographically signed by Apple. You can validate subscription receipt in two ways:

1. Locally/Unsafe: Perform receipt validation immediately after your application launched.
2. Remotely/Safe: Perform receipt validation at server end. Use trusted
   server to connect with App Store.

For more information, see [Receipt Validation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573).

Comment: My problem isn't about validation, but app transition between 2 subscriptions period.

Comment: @sarunw, you always find a gap with local validation because local validation take time to return receipt. So better way is, do it remotely.

Comment: Remote won't have this gap? I think it is the same situation the different is where the validation occur?